# When I have to call base class in event methods in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, events

I have myWidget class. His base class is QWidget. I would like to have in myWidget class, event methods like `keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)`,`paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)` or `mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)`.

I don't know when I have to call base class and when I don't have to call base class in this methods. When I have to do:

```
void myWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
   ...
   QWidget::mousePressEvent(event); // <----- this line
}
```

?

Here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#keyPressEvent there is an information that can be important, when we have popup widgets in application. But this is only reason to call base class? I don't have popup widgets in my application, so I can call base class, but I don't have to?

Here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#paintEvent there isn't any information about differences between call and not call base class. So in paintEvent there is no matter if I call or I don't call base class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will depend on whether the base class implements any logic in those methods, for example if you override the keyPressEvent method of a QLineEdit and you don't invoke `QLineEdit::keyPressEvent(event)` then you won't get the default behavior, the same for paintEvent from other widgets.

In conclusion, you must invoke the base method if you want the default behavior to continue.